# How to configure vpn with NAT behind firewall

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, cisco

My scenario described below where I need to give access to internet clients to access my local LAN through VPN. Established/Running network is below:

- DSL Router (Cisco WRV210) WAN interface IP address: 192.168.10.5
- Local DC/DNS/DHCP (Server 2003) external adapter IP connected to DSL router: 192.168.10.6
- Local DC/DNS/DHCP (Server 2003) internal adapter IP connected to LAN switch: 192.168.30.5
- NAT with VPN is running on server 2003. RRAS Enabled.
- Windows XP Client IP connected to switch: 192.168.30.10 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.30.5
- TCP Port 1723 and VPN Passthrough (IPSec/PPTP/L2TP) enabled on DSL router.

I am still unable to get connected the internet vpn user to my xp client. What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried canyouseeme.org? where you can check your external ip to see if the router actually has these ports open? Also it would be better to do NAPT on the ADSL router along with passthrough. so forward the port 1723 to your external adapter of the server

Comment: canyouseeme.org is unable to access any port on my public ip even port 80. But how the web inbound/outbound is working?

Thanks

Comment: your inbound/outbound is working because of what's know as NAT. for publishing your RRAS server on your router, you have to use NAPT.

Comment: you can use Cisco Configuration Professional to setup the NAPT rules to forward port 1723 from your router to the Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco Configuration Professional is unable to connect to cisco WRV210 dsl router.
I have tested by making a local vpn connection to my 2003 RRAS server, and client is able to connect to the server. So issue is on gateway dsl router that is not going to accept the vpn connection and passing it to the 2003 RRAS server. I have checked all vpn settings on dsl router but no luck!